# Error installing Fedora

Tags: linux, boot, usb, fedora

I have this error when I try to install Fedora 30 on my LG Gram 15z990 using a usb for the installation:

```
dppath: \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI
path:   NULL
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\NULL - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\NULL: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

I have Windows 10 installed and I recently had Ubuntu installed but I deleted it. I don't know if the issue could be caused by that.

I have tried different USB's and softwares to make it bootable so it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Same problem. Any help would be useful. I have LG Gram 14Z990

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable secure boot.

You can get to the BIOS menu by pressing F2 on boot.

Comment: Fedora actually has secureboot support. Might be a different issue

Comment: It does, but it's not guaranteed to work. On my LG Gram I got the same error as OP until I disabled secure boot

Comment: Hi @JeffK I have an LG Gram also and I disabled secure boot and remove signatures and still have this message. I created the USB boot using Ubuntu 18 in my older laptop. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Obtained from [this Korean blog](https://blog.1day1.org/596):

Inside the USB drive go to `\EFI\BOOT\`, copy `grubx64.efi` and rename the copy to `NULL` (not `NULL.efi` but simply `NULL`)

It worked for me.